# Is there any way to more efficiently check if all the letters in a word are in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For a research paper, I am simulating rounds of the Channel 4 Program Countdown's letters round. Essentially, a board of 9 random letters are put up, and players must try and find words made up of the letters given of as high length as they can.

I'm currently using the code:

```
for word in sowpods:
        testboard = list(board)
        count = 0
        for letter in word:
            if letter in testboard:
                testboard.remove(letter)
                count += 1
        if len(word) == count:
            length.append(len(word))
    if len(length) == 0:
        return 0
    return max(length)
```

to create a list of dictionary words (a SOWPODS .txt file imported into the kernel) that can be created from the board, and then returning the longest word possible for statistical analysis (this is part of a function that simulates a round of Countdown). But, from what I can imagine is due to the repeated for loops, if statements and list edits, this is extremely slow when scaled up to larger samples of 500 or so boards. Is there a more efficient way to check if a word can be created from the board?

I tried using sets; my original test was:

```
set(word) <= set(board)
```

but this method ignored repeats, so for example if the board was [a, e, h, s, l,..) it would count "Hassle" as a possible word despite only one S being available. Ideally I'd love a datatype halfway between a list and a set, where order doesn't matter but number of the same element does, but that doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: Could you share a short version of what SOWPODS contains, and with this sample, a small example of what you'd consider an acceptable answer ?

Comment: @Xhattam SOWPODS is the official Scrabble dictionary - similar to the regular dictionary but does not contain proper nouns, suffixes, prefixes etc (which are likewise not allowed in Countdown). An example would be if I used the list ['e', 'o', 'a', 'm', 'c', 't', 'c', 'w', 'y'], the results would be words like 'mate', 'atom', or 'camote'

Comment: Note that your code can't be executed as provided (you don't show us any functions but you have `return` statements, and you have some issues with your indentation). If you fix that, it will help us give you more readily-usable code. I think I have an illustrative example of something that will work faster for you regardless, that you can easily enough drop into your function if that's how you have this implemented.

Comment: @Miney I notice that you edited some solutions into the question - please don't do this, as it makes it no longer a question. Readers can see that your question has answers by scrolling down to them. If your solution is different from the answers below then you can write your own answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One speed-up you can implement is to reorganizer the logic so that the letter-by-letter loop ends the moment a non-matching letter is encountered. This will speed up your code, on average, in direct proportion to the number of letters not allowed.

```
def wordsearch(board, sowpods):
    length = []
    for word in sowpods:
        testboard = list(board)
        count = 0
        for letter in word:
            if letter in testboard:
                testboard.remove(letter)
                count += 1
        if len(word) == count:
            length.append(len(word))
    if len(length) == 0:
        return 0
    return max(length)

def find_matches(allowed, dictionary):
    allowed_list = list(allowed)
    match_words = []
    for word in dictionary:    
        good = True
        for letter in word:
            if letter not in allowed_list:
                good = False
                break
        if good == True:
            match_words.append(len(word))    
    return max(match_words)

import timeit
start_time = timeit.default_timer()
allowed = 'iptneazol'
result = wordsearch(allowed, sb_list)
# code you want to evaluate
elapsed = timeit.default_timer() - start_time
print(elapsed)
>>>0.6867701730000135

start_time = timeit.default_timer()
allowed = 'iptneazol'
result = find_matches(allowed, sb_list)
elapsed = timeit.default_timer() - start_time
print(elapsed)
>>>0.10806877499999246
```

This also solves the issue of an allowed letter appearing twice since the code does not transform the allowed list. For even more efficiency, you could rewrite the for loops as list comprehensions that call service functions, or use iterators/generators.

Comment: Thank you, this method is certainly faster - but it seems for some reason it isn't giving the same result? When I used ['e', 'o', 'a', 'm', 'c', 't', 'c', 'w', 'y'] as an example list, my original method gave 6 consistently (which, using an online checker is a correct result) but if I run it repeatedly using your method it produces 9, which is not correct.

Comment: Furthermore, checking with it printing the words shows that it does indeed solve part of the allowed letter issue, but lets slip through some (but not all) words with disallowed double letters (e.g. with previous board, 'acca' was in list)

Comment: I think I am misunderstanding the task. My function will return the longest word with composed wholly of letters from the example list whether or not all the letters appear in the word, allowing any number of repeats and indifferent of two of the same letter in a row. If there are additional rules that you didn't mention in your post, you should be able to edit my general approach to satisfy those criteria. The key point is leaving the loop when abad result is encountered, so additional rules should make it go even faster.

Comment: Yeah I think slightly - but I modified the code to work for my purposes (by re-adding the allowed list transformation; the point is that an allowed letter is not allowed more times than it is present on the board, e.g. in Scrabble where if you only have one A tile you can only use A once). Thank you so much for the help, it's sped up the code a lot!

Comment: That makes sense. Feel free to edit my solution or tell me how to change it. Also, now I'm watching Countdown on Youtube, so there goes my afternoon. :)

Answer (score 1):

> a datatype halfway between a list and a set, where order doesn't matter but number of the same element does

`collections.Counter` does what you want. You'll have to implement the comparison logic yourself, though.

Comment: This is a really cool module and it doesn't seem to speed up the code especially well but is pretty useful for general efficiency, thank you for bringing it to light!

Answer (score 0):

I felt bad that my `Counter` solution ended up being a lot slower than I thought, so I took your updated code and sped it up a bit:

```
def check_board(sowpods, board):
    length = []
    board = list(board)  # only perform once
    for word in sowpods:
        if len(word) > len(board):
            continue  # short circuit when too long
        on_board = True
        testboard = board.copy()  # our temp board
        for letter in word:
            if letter not in testboard:
                on_board = False
                break
            else:
                testboard.remove(letter)
        if on_board:
            length.append(len(word))
    return max(length)
```

Testing speed with `board = 'eoamctcwy'.upper()`, we have:

- Your original code:

  ```
  # 398 ms ± 40.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
  ```
- Your updated code:

  ```
  # 185 ms ± 24 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
  ```
- This code:

  ```
  # 83.4 ms ± 2.99 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
  ```

The short circuit avoids checking letters for words that you know are too long to fit on the board. This will have diminishing returns if you use larger boards, and you won't see any effect from it if you use a board as large as the largest words in the dictionary.

By avoiding creating a list every iteration, you basically avoid some overhead and save a few milliseconds. Apparently `list.copy()` is faster than building a list from data, or at least it was on my machine when I tested with and without that change.

I also tried replacing the list for length with `length = 0` and just update it to `max(length, len(word))` when appropriate, but that didn't seem to save any time.

Comment: Oh thank you! I've really learned a lot about writing questions and giving info from this; the way I imported SOWPODS didn't import any words longer than 9 (the board size), but your presentation (like I wasn't aware that if on_board was equivalent to if on_board == true) has made the code a little neater, and presentation of code is part of the marking criteria for the project, so thank you for that tidbit!